# How can I move my user profile on Windows 8.1 64 Bit?

Tags: file-transfer, file-permissions

I have two hard drives C: solid state with the operating system installed and D: for back up.  I would like to **move my User profile** from C: to D: to free up space on C:
Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Are you aware that moving your profile will render future upgrades useless?

Comment: Do not move the whole user profile. See http://www.zdnet.com/article/dont-move-your-windows-user-profiles-folder-to-another-drive/ for the reasons. You can move the user data directories (Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures, and so on), see http://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-7-and-ssds-cutting-your-system-drive-down-to-size/2/ for a supported way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think... you can move the entire Users folder from the C: drive to the D: drive, and create a 'symbolic link'.

I suggest taking a system restore image before hand.

To copy the files...

```
robocopy /copyall /mir /xj C:\Users D:\Users
```

To create the link...

```
mklink /D /J C:\Users D:\Users
```